# Is there any way to make group name always displayed and only the childs to get scrolled in expandale list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have table layout and then expandable listview  in a root Linear Layout.

-LinearLayout
   --TableLayout
   --Expandable List
-LineraLayout

But when clicked on the Expandable List view and scrolled, even the Group Name goes below the table layout.

Is there any way I can make the group name always displayed and only the childs to get scrolled?

Comment: No, that's the default behaviour of ExpandableListView....You could make your own Expandable Listview which exhibits your functionality.